# Is there a valid list of Facebook domains exposed in API calls?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an app where we'd like to whitelist domains used by Facebook, and exposed in the results of api calls.

By googling around, I've found what appears to be at least a short list [here on the Facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/additional-configuration/domains#domains)

```
*.facebook.com 80/443
*.akamaihd.net 80/443
*.fbcdn.net 80/443
*.fb.me 80/443
*.fbsbx.com 80/443
```

And I've found what appears to be a list of valid IP ranges for Facebook, [listed on this site](https://www.peeringdb.com/asn/32934), or attainable by running the following command:

`whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934`

but I'm looking for an official (or unofficial) list of Facebook **domains**, and can't seem to find one.

Is there an official list of Facebook domains exposed by API calls?

Comment: There is no official one. Why do you need one?

Comment: @WizKid - Thanks for the feedback. It's part of a security review - investigating whether or not we can identify content by domain, for both Facebook and Twitter. We have links that are parsed from Facebook private messages, and stored in a DB. Later on these links may be retrieved for serving or analysis, and we want to identify the links that are truly Facebook links - ie content served from Facebook domains, and not some third party domain, as may happen in a private message.

Comment: There is no API access to a user's private messages any more - so this rather sounds like what you are doing is not even legal to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe - how so? do you have a link somewhere that says this is no longer supported? We're only using their public APIs so I'm sure what we're doing is fully supported/legal. Though I'm not working on the "reading private messages" part of our app, a quick google shows me it seems to be supported still, [with the right permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/conversation/messages)

Comment: Ah, so you mean messages between a user and a page - yes, those are still accessible. I thought you were referring to private messages between users - those aren't accessible via API any more.

Comment: Cool... thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no", there is no official list.

Here's the best guess at a list I've got for what it's worth:

```
akamaihd.net
fbcdn.net
fb.me
fbsbx.com
```

and for twitter, who I also was interested in:

```
twitter.*
twimg.com
t.co
```

Comment: Also: 
www.facebook.com - authentication/authorization
graph.facebook.com - the vast majority of the API
graph-video.facebook.com - video upload
graph.atlassolutions.com - add management